# Why the definition of \hrulefill in LaTeX ended with \kern\z@?

Tags: macros

In plainTeX, `\hrulefill` is defineded as below:

`\def\hrulefill{\leaders\hrule\hfill}`

On the other hand, it's definded as below in LaTeX:

`\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\hfill\kern\z@}`

I understand `\leavevmode` is needed to supress error in vertical modes. However, I cannot understand why `\kern\z@` is needed for the definition.

I have already  verified that nothing was outputted with  `\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\hfill}` , however I cannot understand it well why such a thing happen.

According to source2e.pdf, there is only the description that `\kern\z@` is needed to make it work in ‘tabular’ and ‘array’ environments, and I have not understood it well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In latex `tabular` and similar environments you can use

```
... &  foo & ...
```

or

```
...&foo& ...
```

or

```
....&
 foo &
....
```

and get the same result. People probably just expect that to happen naturally but in the underlying alignment primitives these would give different output for the same reason `\fbox{foo}` is not the same as `\fbox{ foo }`

To make it work, LaTeX uses `\ignorespaces` at the start of the cell, and `\unskip` at the end, but an `\unskip` would also remove `\leaders` like the rule fill unless the leaders are guarded by something that `\unskip` does not remove.